# Исключить 3 месяца из массив дат в php

Tags: php, массивы, дата

Нужно подсчитать 9 месяцев с текущего момента

но исключить 3 месяца лета (Июнь(6) Июль(7) Август(8)).

Т.е. если брать с текущего момента 10-2015 + 9 месяцев = 07-2015

а нужно 10-2015 + 9 месяцев = 10-2016

Посоветуйте, что можно придумать?

Comment: Прибавляйте сразу год :)

Comment: в том то и проблема что кол-во месяцев можно быть от 1 до 9=) поэтому год не вариант

Comment: Сделал) Пруф такой: $start = strtotime($start_date);
  $end = strtotime($end_date);
  
  $arrayOfDates = array();
  $newm = array();
  for($i=$start; $i<$end; $i+=2592000){
    list($year,$month) = explode("|",date("Y|n",$i));
    if($month == 6 OR $month == 7 OR $month == 8){
     $month = $month + 3;
    }
    $arrayOfDates[$year][] = $month;
  }

Comment: Оформите как ответ на свой вопрос. Это можно делать.

Comment: @Влад В вашем решении есть ошибка. Добавил ответ ниже.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно вашей задаче, нужно получить 9 месяцев от текущей даты включительно. По всей видимости в массиве должны быть только числа - порядковый номер месяца.

Вот ваше решение (даты добавил на угад):

```
$start_date = "2013-01-01";
$end_date = "2015-10-30";
$start = strtotime($start_date);
$end = strtotime($end_date);
$arrayOfDates = array();
$newm = array();
for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i += 2592000) {
    list($year, $month) = explode("|", date("Y|n", $i));
    if ($month == 6 OR $month == 7 OR $month == 8) {
        $month = $month + 3;
    }
    $arrayOfDates[$year][] = $month;
}

var_dump($arrayOfDates);
```

Вот результат:

```
array(3) {
  [2013]=>
  array(13) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "4"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "5"
    [5]=>
    string(1) "5"
    [6]=>
    int(9)
    [7]=>
    int(10)
    [8]=>
    int(11)
    [9]=>
    string(1) "9"
    [10]=>
    string(2) "10"
    [11]=>
    string(2) "11"
    [12]=>
    string(2) "12"
  }
  [2014]=>
  array(12) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "4"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "5"
    [5]=>
    int(9)
    [6]=>
    int(10)
    [7]=>
    int(11)
    [8]=>
    string(1) "9"
    [9]=>
    string(2) "10"
    [10]=>
    string(2) "11"
    [11]=>
    string(2) "12"
  }
  [2015]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "4"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "5"
    [5]=>
    int(9)
    [6]=>
    int(10)
    [7]=>
    int(11)
    [8]=>
    string(1) "9"
    [9]=>
    string(2) "10"
  }
}
```

Как не трудно видеть - данные не верные.

Если задание я правильно понял, то вот код:

```
function getIncrementedData()
{
    $monthForExclude = array(6, 7, 8);
    $currentMonth = (int)date('n');
    $monthInYear = 12;
    $months = array();

    for ($m = $currentMonth; $m < $currentMonth + $monthInYear; $m++) {
        $month = ($m > $monthInYear) ? $m - $monthInYear : $m;
        if (!in_array($month, $monthForExclude)) {
            $months[] = $month;
        }
    }
    var_dump($months);
}
```

Результат:

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  int(10)
  [1]=>
  int(11)
  [2]=>
  int(12)
  [3]=>
  int(1)
  [4]=>
  int(2)
  [5]=>
  int(3)
  [6]=>
  int(4)
  [7]=>
  int(5)
  [8]=>
  int(9)
}
```

Положим нужно вывести год и месяц.
Тогда модифицируется:

```
function getIncrementedData()
{
    $monthForExclude = array(6, 7, 8);
    $currentMonth = (int)date('n');
    $startDate = date('Y-m-15');
    $monthInYear = 12;
    $months = array();

    for ($m = 1; $m <= $monthInYear; $m++) {
        $month = $m + $currentMonth - 1;
        $month = ($month > $monthInYear) ? $month - $monthInYear : $month;
        var_dump($month);
        if (!in_array($month, $monthForExclude)) {
            $newdate = strtotime("+".($m-1)." month", strtotime($startDate));
            $months[] = date('Y-m', $newdate);
        }
    }
    var_dump($months);
}
```

Результат:

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "2015-10"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "2015-11"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "2015-12"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "2016-01"
  [4]=>
  string(7) "2016-02"
  [5]=>
  string(7) "2016-03"
  [6]=>
  string(7) "2016-04"
  [7]=>
  string(7) "2016-05"
  [8]=>
  string(7) "2016-09"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Это задача на пересечение интервалов. У вас есть два события: начало и начало + 9 месяцев. И ещё два: начало и конец лета. Нужно найти «конец» с учётом правила: Пересечение исходного интервала с летом автоматически добавляет это перекрытие к концу лета, сдвигая исходный «конец» на после августа:

```
s--------e             старт + простые 9 мес.
x
       S------E        это лето, типа
=
-------xxx             пересечение

s------S------E--e     итоговый конец
```

Т.о. надо найти перекрытие данных 9 мес. с летом и добавить их к концу лета. Берём старт, добавляем 9 месяцев (*определитесь*: [календарно](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.add.php) или просто фикс. число секунд). Добавляем ближайшее после старта 1-е Июня 00:00:00 (*определитесь*, в какой временнОй зоне всё происходит, не попадаете ли на смену зимнего и летнего времени) и 1-е Сентября 00:00:00.

Итого в массиве 4 времени. Массив отсортировать по возрастанию, и «двигаться» слева направо. Варианты:

1. `seSE` после старта вторым идёт конец – ок, ничего не добавляем. Пронесло.
2. `sSeE` после старта идёт начало лета, потом конец и конец лета (как на примере выше) – добавляем пересечение к концу лета.
3. `sSEe` после старта идут начало и конец лета, затем свой конец. Просто прибавляем длину лета к исходному концу.
4. `SsEe` после старта идёт конец лета. Т.е. мы начали посреди лета. К исх. концу добавить это расстояние между стартом и концом лета.
5. `SsESeE` ещё может быть что мы захватили два лета - начали в конце августа, и дотянулись до начала следующего. Нет, не может, если интервал ровно 9 месяцев. Хотя.. Проверьте такую возможность, всякие високосные годы и пр. leap seconds. Добро пожаловать в [адъ календарей и временных зон](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY) )